# Struts2 xwork Type Conversion with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, type-conversion, crud

What is the best way to convert types in a Struts2 application?

Right now I want to create a CRUD for a certain hibernate entity in my application.  Say I wanted to change the `Account` that a `User` is associated with. I can just pass in the parameter `user.account.id` with a specific value, provided that I have all of the proper getters/setters.

This works perfectly fine when creating an object for the first time, where the account would be null. This makes ognl create a new account object, and set the id to what was passed in.

The problem happens when trying to change the encapsulated `Account` object. Using the same `user.account.id` parameter, ognl interprets this as `getUser().getAccount().setId(param)`. Hibernate interprets this as an attempt to change the primary key.

I understand why it does this, I am just wondering if there is  better way for handling this case. This is very common in our application, and I don't want to have to keep creating multiple objects and marshaling them over before I save them via hibernate.

Does anyone no a better way to solve this problem in struts2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Type Converters for Persistence

Create a type converter for the entity and then just pass `user.account`, rather than `user.account.id`. This will invoke `getUser().setAccount(account)` and wont cause you the headaches.

When you update the record, just pass `user.account` as a hidden field in the form.

As for a widespread solution for your entities, you have a few options:

### Multiple Converters

Create an abstract type converter that handles most of the logic so that you have a subclass-per-entity that is really lightweight. Register each converter in your `xwork-conversion.properties`.

### Interface-Driven Converter

The approach that I use is that I have an interface called `IdBasedJpaEntity` which 99.9% of my entities implement. It defines a `getId()` method of type `Integer`. I then have a `JpaDAORegistry` singleton class that I create when my app starts. I register each of my entities with it and it constructs a single instance of each DAO (basically, a de-facto singleton). I have a map of entity class to DAO instance. This allows my type converter to look up the appropriate DAO instance for any given `IdBasedJpaEntity`, allowing me to have a single `JpaEntityConverter` class that works with any entity that implements the interface. This route is a little bit more work up front, but has proven highly reusable for me.

Comment: I liked you approach, but I made some modifications. I gave the converter a reference to the EntityManager. Since the `em` has a `find` method that takes a class object (which is what gets passed in the conversion method anyway) and a primary key. This is working for me for now, and seems fairly simple.